# null checking refactoring in java

Tags: java, refactoring

We have two classes:

```
class Foo {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    ...
    getter...setter...
}

class Boo {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    ...
    getter...setter...
}
```

Assume that Foo and Bar are different but some fields are the same.

here is code I want to do:

```
  private void map(foo f) {
    Boo b = new Boo();
    if (f.getA() != null)  b.setA(f.getA());
    if (f.getB() != null)  b.setB(f.getB());
    if (f.getC() != null)  b.setC(f.getC());
    ....
  }
```

3 fields are not a big deal.

But if there are a lot of fields, there would be a lot of if() too.

I'm wondering there is a nice automatic and program nice ways for it in java or C++.

Comment: Consider having an array or list of strings, instead of many separate string fields.

Comment: It's not clear why you need the conditions at all. Are you defaulting the values to something other than null?

Comment: what happens to `A` of `b` if `A` of `f` is `null`? If it remains `null` you can get rid of the conditions. Also, I would create a class `Bar` with common fields and extend it.

Comment: that's just an example. the classes are jpa entities. so can't use String or array

Answer (score 2):

Or you may use a mapping framework like eg. Dozer: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/

You would be able to write code like this:

```
Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
Boo destObject = new Boo();
mapper.map(foo, destObject);
```

... and it will copy your properties from one object to the other (using reflection).

With additional configuration you would be able to add conversion logic or non-trivial mapping rules (take value of Foo#prop1 and put it to Boo#prop2) or deep copy of an object graph. And many more.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `if` statements using functional interfaces and method references  like this.

```
static <X> void setIfNotNull(Consumer<X> setter, Supplier<X> getter) {
    X value = getter.get();
    if (value != null)
        setter.accept(value);
}

private void map(Foo f) {
    Boo b = new Boo();
    setIfNotNull(b::setA, f::getA);
    setIfNotNull(b::setB, f::getB);
    setIfNotNull(b::setC, f::getC);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**`std::optional`**!

In C++17 this is super automatable, (before C++17, you can just fetch any implementation of an `optional` class and have the code work the same way)

```
class Container {
public:
    std::array<std::optional<std::string>, 3> three_string_nullables;
};

int main() {
    auto strings = std::array<std::optional<std::string>, 3>{};
    // fill the strings or don't
    auto container = Container{};
    container.three_string_nullables = strings;
}
```

To generalize this, you can consider putting the optionals in a dynamically sized container like a `std::vector`

Answer (score 1):

You can use java reflection API for this task. Reflection allows you to get metadata about classes (like: fields in class, methods and other). Among other things you can invoke class methods. You can take all setters and getters from class, and based on this information can make the necessary calls.

Answer (score 1):

The *real* answer is to step back and look at the requirements that are driving your question.

You see, good OO is about creating *models* aka *abstractions* that represent the "real world elements" your code is dealing with. In a **helpful** way. In that sense, good OO is much more about *behavior* (aka methods) than about *state* (aka fields).

From there: having classes that have **a lot** of fields is a first design smell already. And then having getters/setters on most/all of those fields is making things rather *worse*.

Beyond that: when you have **two** classes A and B. A has 5 fields, B has 7, ... and you find that 3 of those fields are "common" ... the **real** real answer is: create a class C that contains those 3 fields; and put a field of type C into A and B. And yes, the **default** would be to have a C field within A and B - because you [favor composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

So, yes; there are frameworks that help with this. Or you could re-organize your fields into a single Map instance.

But (probably opinionated): I think you should first talk to some real people, review the current solution and ask yourself: "are we doing real OO here; or are our objects nothing but *records* that we move around and that *procedural* code is then working on". In other words - ask yourself if you are really doing OOP here.

Comment: Why not extend C? With the 3 fields protected.

Comment: @Narmer see the update to my answer. Plus: **fields** should be private implementation detail. Making fields protected is the first step into the abyss. It is possible, **sharing** state between classes is again something you avoid in good OOP.

Comment: Use of inheritance is for differential programming. We need an A class that is just like the existing C class, but with a few tweaks and enhancements. In this case, inherit away; it is appropriate because our subclass is still a C class, we want to reuse the entire interface and implementation from the superclass, and our changes are primarily additive. If you find that your subclass is removing things provided by the superclass, question inheriting from that superclass. Unless you are creating an implementation class, you should not inherit from an implementation class.

Comment: But this kind of consideration can be really made only if we knew what the OP is really trying to do, which we do not... :(

Comment: Oh, no, nothing, have an upvote! Simply I was more attracted by the contents than the value here in SO! The only thing I would do is "prettify" it, to make it more readable, but it's just my taste.

Comment: If you want to, put in an edit (I honor *readability* very much), but probably I am biased by my own style; so helpful edits are always welcome. (and I dont shy from "rewarding" editors that do good work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should store your String in a map.

When you fill your foo class you do it using insert.

Then when you want to copy from each other you iterate on the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of members in the class(es), you can use reflection to copy fields.  That will allow you to also copy a `null` value across correctly.  It's a lot of more fragile code, so it's only going to be useful if you have a lot of members.